# Sql not accept '.example' commands c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

my sql command:

```
INSERT INTO LOGS(EventID,Version,Level_,Task,Opcode,Keywords,EventRecordID,Correlation,ThreadID,ProcessID,Channel,Computer,Security)
VALUES 
(4624,0,0,12544,0,0x8020000000000000,911588,null,704,608,Security,ncelik.mst.bbb@mail.com.tr,null)
```

when i execute the code in visual studio 
the error code is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near
>   'mst'. at system.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException,
>   Boolean breakConnection i Action 1 weapCloseInAction)
>    I don't know what is it

Comment: The error in the syntax exactly in 'mst'

Comment: what do you mean i don't understand

Comment: did you try oscar answer ?

Comment: Yes it didn't solved.

Comment: try :  `[ncelik].[mst].bbb@mail.com.tr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ncelik.mst.bbb@mail.com.tr` is an string, it must be enclosed in single quotation marks, like :

```
INSERT INTO LOGS(EventID,Version,Level_,Task,Opcode,Keywords,EventRecordID,Correlation,ThreadID,ProcessID,Channel,Computer,Security)
VALUES 
(4624,0,0,12544,0,0x8020000000000000,911588,null,704,608,Security,'ncelik.mst.bbb@mail.com.tr',null)
```

Comment: i got a mail adress when i send the mail adress i use-> example: string mail ="ncelik.mst.bbb@mail.com------  Insert into ........ values(........,mail,..)

Comment: I don't understand your comment.